# Odata source inside ForEach loop

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am building a SSIS solution on visual studio where the goal is to retrieve all the client numbers from a database table(using a sql task) and loop throught them using a ForEach loop  container and a Data Flow Task. Inside the data flow I am using a odata source where the query option uses that client number.
But I am getting an error because the variables that I am using to insert on that filter query are allways 0 (Data Flow expressions image).

Here are the variables I have created:
BURKS(string) to keep the cliente company
KUNNR(int32) to keep cliente number
Values(object) to store data from the sql task

[Data Flow Task expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZuzM.png)

Table example:

| KUNNR | BURKS |
| --- | --- |
| 623254 | E001 |
| 986 | E005 |

Explaining the steps with a little more detail...
The sql task as a full step result with the sql statement : SELECT TOP 2 KUNNR, BURKS FROM dbo.temp_partners;
The result set have the variable 'Values' (images bellow)

[SQL Task editor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wVBC.png)
[SQL Task editor 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D9PD.png)

The loop container component is set to a 'ADO Foreach enumerator', using the variable 'Values' and I am mapping the 2 returned column on the 2 variables. (images bellow)
[Foreach editor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoJqH.png)
[Foreach editor 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANssJ.png)

I feel that something is not correct on the process, I kinda of new on the technology so any help would be great.